# How can i wait dialog material response to continue my function?

Tags: angular, typescript

In a determined moment of my function i open an material dialog, i need to wait the answer of the dialog to continue my function, but the function is running before i select the confirm dialog.

I try something:

My default function:

```
alteraDadosProduto(){ 
    let confirmouAtualizacaoProduto = this.verificaProdutoPossuIAnuncio();
    if(confirmouAtualizacaoProduto == false){
      return ;
    }

... functions continue
```

My dialog function:

```
verificaProdutoPossuIAnuncio(): boolean{
    if(this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio[0].anuncio.length == 0){
      return true;
    }else{
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogConfirmacaoAtualizacaoAnuncioComponent);
      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if(result == true){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
    })
  }
}
```

How can i wait the result of subscribe to continue my alteraDadosProduto function? Thanks

Comment: Please consider creating a minimal sample stackblitz replicating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe on it, [look at here](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Answer (score 0):

Sory cant writte commnet(low rep).
I am not full understand you.
But if you need to pass data to `result` after dialog close you can for example :

```
    import {MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

    export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
       constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<ModalComponent>) {}

       closeModal() {
           this.dialogRef.close(true); 
//pass data to this.dialogRef.close(yourData) to pass it for component where you open dialog
       }
    }
```

And than you can easy manipulate with result like in your code

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if(result == true){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
```

Sorry if I dont understand you full.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing a function for angular mat-dialog-close it will always call the function while the dialog is open. Hence instead of a function call assign a property for mat-dialog-close.

Answer (score 0):

Declare this into your component :

```
public subject = new Subject<boolean>();
```

Your default function would be :

```
alteraDadosProduto(){ 
    this.subject.subscribe(response => {
       if(response == true){
          // Stuff you want to do...
       } else {
          // Stuff you want to do...
       }
    });
   this.verificaProdutoPossuIAnuncio();
}
```

Your dialog function:

```
verificaProdutoPossuIAnuncio(): void{
    if(this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio[0].anuncio.length == 0){
      return true;
    }else{
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogConfirmacaoAtualizacaoAnuncioComponent);
      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        this.subject.next(result);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: However this will create multiple subscription on alteraDadosProduto() function call. You can move subsribe part to OnInit and that will subscribe only once and you can unsubscribe into OnDestroy life cycle to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [lastValueFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom) from rxjs

```
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogConfirmacaoAtualizacaoAnuncioComponent);
let dialogResult = await lastValueFrom(dialogRef.afterClosed());
if (dialogResult ) {
   ...
}
```